# Series connection of household AC

Tags: electrical-engineering

Household supplies are 110v AC.  Is it possible to series connect two plug points and get 220v AC?

Answer (score 3):

No, when go connect 2 plug points in series you will connect the live from one directly to the neutral of the other. That is a short and will trip the breaker.

Some circuits are wired in split-phase where there are 2 lives and a neutral. Live to live will be 220V and either live to neutral will be 110V. So in that specific case you could get 220V from 2 110V outlets.

But **DON'T DO THAT** especially when you don't know how electricity works. Instead pay an electrician to install a 220V outlet where you need it.